# Como validar que exista un dato en datepicker 1 para habilitar datepicker 2

Tags: condiciones, validación, datepicker

Estoy desarrolando una pagina del sector agropecuario donde se lleva un registro de plantasiones, en la pagina que tengo el problema tengo dos datepicker uno de fecha propuesta y el siguiente es de la fecha real de la plantasion del producto, el problema es que independientemente si ya se propuso una fecha me habilita la fecha real. El punto es que necesito que el datepicker de fecha final solo este activo si y solo si ya existe una fecha propuesta.

````
        <div><mat-label>Fecha propuesta</mat-label></div>
        <mat-form-field
          class="formOutline"
          color="primary"
          appearance="outline"
        >
          <input
            formControlName="sowing_date"
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="pickerSowing_date"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="pickerSowing_date"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #pickerSowing_date></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div><mat-label>Fecha real</mat-label></div>
        <mat-form-field
          class="formOutline"
          color="primary"
          appearance="outline"
        >
          <input
            formControlName="real_date"
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="pickerReal_date"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="pickerReal_date"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #pickerReal_date></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>


events: string[] = [];
  seedTimeForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    type_sowing: [
      { value: '', disabled: this.mode === 'view' },
      [Validators.required],
    ],
    variety: [
      { value: '', disabled: this.mode === 'view' },
      [Validators.required],
    ],
    sowing_date: [{ value: '', disabled: this.mode === 'view' }, []],
    real_date: [{ value: '', disabled: this.mode === 'view' }, []],
  })```
````

Comment: Los tag son necesarios para ayudarnos a saber qué tecnologías usas. Los tag condiciones o validación no nos ayudan en absoluto... por favor, añade los tag de las *tecnologías* empleadas! (Asumo que estás usando alguna versión de Angular en este caso, pero edita la pregunta y añade los tag correspondientes, por favor). También te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para comprender cómo funciona StackOverflow. Bienvenido.

Comment: oye que pena soy nuevo en varias cosas, cuando dices agregar los tags podrías darme algún ejemplo?